# Do cmd Transfer Database VBA

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba, data-transfer

Team

Am trying to copy data from access table to oracle database using transfer database in VBA. But I get an error that says object required . This is the script and don't understand why I get this error

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, _
"ODBC Database", _
"ODBC;DSN=xxx;UID=User;PWD=#007;LANGUAGE=us_english;" _
& "Database=xxx", _
acTable, _
tblaccess, _
User.tbloracle, False, False
```

Answer (score 0):

From Access to Oracle you need `acExport`, not `acImport`.

The error is probably `User.tbloracle`, I guess you want

```
"User." & tbloracle
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the heads up on the acexport. This method of "User." & tbloracle triggers another run time error '3450' which says syntax in error. Incomplete query clause

Comment: Well, what *is* your target table in Oracle? I suggest to supply the full actual name for the `Destination` parameter as constant string while testing.

Comment: The table name is rpt.

Comment: And what happens if you change `User.tbloracle` to `"rpt"` ?

Comment: Sorry Andre. I was out on Vacation and the worst part is the issue still persists and when I change it to just the table name it puts up on error called ORA-1747